# Laravel Relationship with Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables named `products_description` with primary key `products_id` and second table `orders_products` with foreign key `products_id` that link these two tables. We can say that a product can be in many orders.

I have created the following models for both tables.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class products_description extends Model
{
  protected $table = "products_description";
  protected $primaryKey = "products_id";

  public function orders_products()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Orders_product','products_id','products_id');
    return $this->hasMany(Orders_product::class);
  }
}
```

and

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Orders_product extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "orders_products_id";
}
```

The following code in my controller class

```
class products_controller extends Controller
{
    public function show1(Products_description $Products_description)
  {
    return view('products.show',compact('Products_description'));   
  }
}
```

The following code in my show.blade.php file

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')

{{ $Products_description->products_name }}

@foreach($Products_description->orders_products as $Orders_product)
  {{ $Orders_product->orders_id }}
@endforeach

@stop
```

Where I want to display the product name first and then the order ids in which this products exists. But I am getting the following error. Without foreach loop, the product name is displaying fine.

Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp\www\laravel1\resources\views\products\show.blade.php)

```
in 0bb3f93ed324818ac22ad70d47add00a1c4f8a7c.php line 11
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\wamp\www\laravel1\storage\framework\views/0bb3f93ed324818ac22ad70d47add00a1c4f8a7c.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'Products_description' => object(products_description))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\wamp\www\laravel1\resources\views/products/show.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'Products_description' => object(products_description))) in View.php line 149
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that I was using two relationships `belongsTo` and `hasMany` in my `products_description` model and was not using `foreign_key` and `local_key` in my `hasMany` relationship. Which was actually the problem. I removed the `belongsTo` relation and added the `foreign_key` and `local_key` to `hasMany` relation and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

first this function have two returns, should remove first one:

```
public function orders_products()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Orders_product','products_id','products_id');
    return $this->hasMany(Orders_product::class);
}
```

then in you controller function :

```
public function show1(Products_description $Products_description)
{
    return view('products.show',compact('Products_description'));   
}
```

you can't just `compact('Products_description')`, because it's an instance.

```
public function show1(Products_description $Products_description)
{
    $products = $Products_description->all();
    return view('products.show',compact('products'));   
}
```

above is what you need , or just `$products = $Products_description->find($productID);`

Comment: By removing the first line from model, it gives the following error Unknown column 'orders_products.products_description_id' in 'where clause. Because Laravel or Eloquent try to obtain the primary and foreign key from the table names so how can we define the primary and foreign key that are different than the table names.

Comment: Secondly, I have used 'Route Model Binding' and 'type hinting' where I can use compact('Products_description') which successfully displays the the product name on the show.blade.php and looks like that is not the cause of this error.